# Plotting problem

Tags: warning-messages, vector, parametric-functions

I was wondering why I keep receiving the error message

> ```
> "Derivative should be a triple of numbers, or scaled form"
> ```

from the following code

```
uT[t_] := Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]]]

vN[t_] := Simplify[uT'[t]/Norm[uT'[t]]]

vB[t_] := Simplify[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]/Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]]]

N[Evaluate[uT[7 Pi/2]]]
```

> ```
> {0., 0.894427, 0.447214}
> ```

```
N[Evaluate[vN[7 Pi/2]]]
```

> ```
> {-(2./Sqrt[4. + 0.00900633 Abs[2.23607 - 1. Derivative[1][Norm][{0., 3., 1.5}]]^2]), 
> 0., ( 2.23607 - 1. Derivative[1][Norm][{0., 3., 1.5}])/Sqrt[444.132 + Abs[2.23607 - 1.
> Derivative[1][Norm][{0., 3., 1.5}]]^2]}
> ```

```
N[Evaluate[vB[7 Pi/2]]]
```

> ```
> {0.0944772, -0.445213, 0.890426}
> ```

```
N[Evaluate[uT[13 Pi/2]]]
```

> ```
> {0., -0.607287, -0.794483}
> ```

```
N[Evaluate[vN[13 Pi/2]]]
```

> ```
> (*out56*)     
> {50696.9/Sqrt[2.57017*10^9 + 9. Abs[2534.84 + 1539.38 Derivative[1][Norm][{0., 
> -2.29314, -3.}]]^2], (3. (2534.84 + 1539.38 Derivative[1][Norm][{0., -2.29314, 
> -3.}]))/Sqrt[ 2.57017*10^9 + 9. Abs[2534.84 + 1539.38 Derivative[1][Norm][{0., 
> -2.29314, -3.}]]^2], 0.}
> ```

```
N[Evaluate[vB[13 Pi/2]]]
```

> ```
> {0.118335, -0.7889, 0.60302}
> ```

```
Cter = ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 10 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick]];

stp = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], Black, Sphere[r[0], .5]}];

TNBPlot = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[.07], Thickness[.15], Yellow, 
                      Arrow[{N[uT[7 Pi/2]], N[uT[13 Pi/2]]}], Green, 
                      Arrow[{N[vN[7 Pi/2]], N[vN[13 Pi/2]]}], Blue, 
                      Arrow[{N[vB[7 Pi/2]], N[vB[13 Pi/2]]}]}];

Show[Cter, stp, TNBPlot, PlotRange -> All]
```

I did narrow it down to the equation to `(*out56*)`, the equation for the Normal Vector. I haven't posted the actual function, because there's a bunch of questions up already pertaining to it, and I didn't want to give the impression that I'm trying to offload my homework onto anyone. Additionally, when I did have it working, I couldn't get the vectors to display properly. Could that possibly be due to the program considering the vectors and the actual 3D-Parametric plot as separate entities or something?

Comment: Your error message is saying (I think) "Coordinate (...) should be a triple of numbers." The points can't be plotted because `vN` doesn't seem to produce any numbers, just `Norm'` expressions, which causes that error.

Comment: Could you please add the definition of `r` too? Never, NEVER assume that we can figure out its value, or that we can solve the problem in a symbolic way for any `r`!

Answer (score 2):

There are probably more elegant answers. I post this for illustrative purposes:

```
r[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], t}    
tangent[t_] := Normalize@(r'[t])
normal[t_] := Normalize@(r''[t])
binormal[t_] := Normalize@(Cross[tangent[t], normal[t]])

vec = Arrow /@ {{r[#], r[#] + tangent[#]}, {r[#], 
       r[#] + normal[#]}, {r[#], r[#] + binormal[#]}} &[Pi/2];
Show[ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], Graphics3D[vec]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to your definitions of `uT`, `uN`, `uB`.  That will take care of such terms as `Norm'`.

```
uT[t_] := Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]] // ComplexExpand]

vN[t_] := Simplify[uT'[t]/Norm[uT'[t]] // ComplexExpand]

vB[t_] := Simplify[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]/Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]] //  ComplexExpand]
```

Example:

```
r[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t], E^t}

N[Evaluate[vN[13 Pi/2]]]
(* {0.707107, -0.707107, 9.57279*10^-10} *)
```